# What is wrong with my Java recursive fibonacci function?

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

I've just written this piece but for some reason in the console I get some numbers which look right but are in the wrong order, and some numbers are repeated. What is the problem?

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;

        fibonacci(n);
    }

    public static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if(n == 0) {
            System.out.println(0);
            return 0;
        } else if(n == 1) {
            System.out.println(1);
            return 1;
        } else {
            int result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some test cases? Like, "results for test `n=0`, results for test `n=1`..." etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program calculates the Fibonacci number correctly.  It's the last number printed, in the top-level call to `fibonacci`.

Some numbers are repeatedly printed because they are being calculated more than once.  `fibonacci(5)` calls `fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)`, which calls `fibonacci(3) + fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(2) + fibonacci(1)`, and we already have two separate recursive calls that have the same argument.  There are more repeated calls as the recursive calls descend further.

For a low input such as `5`, this is ok, but for higher numbers, you will have performance problems, because this algorithm is exponential in nature.  The complexity is O(2<sup>n</sup>).  Your current print statements are highlighting all the extra calculations that are being performed.  You can remove them, but the algorithm is still exponential in complexity.

Even though your program is currently correct, it is possible to eliminate the exponential complexity, replacing it with linear complexity (O(n)), by storing the results of intermediate calls to `fibonacci` in an array.  This way, each intermediate step is only calculated once.

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to see the Fibonacci sequence up to the set term, remove all outputs from your `fibonacci(int n)` method and just have one `print` method in main that is in a `for` loop from 1 up to your set term.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 5;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n ; i++) {
        System.out.print(fibonacci(i) + " ");
    }
}

public static int fibonacci(int n) {
    if(n == 0) {
       return 0;
    } else if(n == 1) {
       return 1;
    } else {
       return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise that you remove those print statements.  They are confusing you.

This is the way recursion works: you pop method calls off the stack to evaluate them.

This looks fine to me:

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.println(String.format("i: %5d fib(i): %10d", i, fibonacci(i)));
        }
    }

    public static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if(n == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if(n == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your function is recursive, there are multiple prints per fibonacci number. If you don't want this, move the printing outside the function

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;

        System.out.println(fibonacci(n));
    }

    public static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if(n == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else if(n == 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            int result = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

If, however, you intended the prints for tracing what the function does, then it is already behaving as expected. Recursive fibonacci computes the same values multiple times, which is why it is so inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is perfectly fine, the extra prints are from the recursive calls to your `fibonacci` method. The call stack of `fib` for 4 is:

```
                         f(4)
                  /                 \
          f(4-1)          +            f(4-2)
        /          \                /         \
   f(3-1)   +     f(3-2)  +      f(2-1)  +  f(2-2)
    /      \        |               |          |
 f(2-1) + f(2-2)    |               |          |
    |        |      |               |          |
    1   +    0  +   1      +        1     +    0
                        3
```

(Note: f is short for `fibonacci`)

Each one of the calls prints to the console, resulting in the extra and out of order numbers.